# VLookup in SQL? - Joining to only pick out the top row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get just the first row from a JOIN in SQL. Something similiar to Vlookup in Excel.

I have the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE customer_lookup (
    customer_product varchar(50),
    supplier_product varchar(50),
    customer_code varchar(10)
)

CREATE TABLE supplier (
    part_number varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO customer_lookup (
                customer_product,
                supplier_product,
                customer_code ) VALUES ('CONTAINER', 'BOX', 'CUST01')  
INSERT INTO customer_lookup (
                customer_product,
                supplier_product,
                customer_code ) VALUES ('CONTAINER', 'BOX', 'CUST02')
INSERT INTO customer_lookup (
                customer_product,
                supplier_product,
                customer_code ) VALUES ('FABRIC', 'MATERIAL', 'CUST01')

INSERT INTO supplier ( part_number ) VALUES ('FABRIC')
INSERT INTO supplier ( part_number ) VALUES ('CONTAINER')
INSERT INTO supplier ( part_number ) VALUES ('PAINT')
```

and my query is

```
SELECT
    s.part_number, c.supplier_product, c.customer_code
FROM
    supplier s
    LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT * FROM customer_lookup t 
        ) c

    ON s.part_number = c.customer_product
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/716b5/1

The result I am trying to get is

```
part_number         supplier_product    customer_code
FABRIC              MATERIAL            CUST01
CONTAINER           BOX                 CUST01
PAINT               (null)              (null)
```

but the above SQL query produces

```
part_number supplier_product    customer_code
FABRIC      MATERIAL            CUST01
CONTAINER   BOX                 CUST01
CONTAINER   BOX                 CUST02
PAINT       (null)              (null)
```

I don't care that the row with CONTAINER is missing customer_code CUST02. I just need to top one

I have tried

```
SELECT
    s.part_number, c.supplier_product, c.customer_code
FROM
    supplier s
    LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 * FROM customer_lookup t 
        ) c

    ON s.part_number = c.customer_product
```

but this just nulls out both FABRIC and PAINT rows

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: SQL tables don't really have a "first" row, so if you want to use `SELECT TOP 1` of anything then you really also need to include `ORDER BY` as well, otherwise you're likely to get unexpected results.

Comment: I would say *must* rather than *really*

Comment: I think this gets what you want: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/48d55/1 but I don't think it is using the most optimal execution plan, one of the answers below is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP BY and MAX to achieve what you're looking for

```
SELECT
    s.part_number, c.supplier_product, MAX(c.customer_code)
FROM
    supplier s
    LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT * FROM customer_lookup t 
        ) c

    ON s.part_number = c.customer_product
GROUP BY s.part_number, c.supplier_product
```

For every `part_number` and `supplier_product` unique identifying combination, you want the highest `customer_code` value.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care which row qualifies as the *top* row, as long as it returns one row at most, then you can use the `row_number` window function with `order by null`.

```
SELECT s.part_number, c.supplier_product, c.customer_code
  FROM supplier s
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT *,
                    row_number() over (partition by customer_product order by null) as rn
              FROM customer_lookup) c
    ON s.part_number = c.customer_product
   AND c.rn = 1
```

If you do care which row gets picked, then just modify the `order by` clause accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `CROSS APPLY` to get your results, the main benefit here is that you are not using aggregation (`GROUP BY`)

```
SELECT
    s.part_number, c.supplier_product, c.customer_code
FROM
    supplier s
    CROSS APPLY 
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 * FROM customer_lookup t 
            WHERE s.part_number = t.customer_product
            ORDER BY t.customer_code
        ) c
```

You should also add an `ORDER BY` to ensure the results are order the way you want them to be (I have added this in for you).

You should also define columns that you are using rather than using an asterisk (*) but that's up to you (I've left this as is for now)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/716b5/17

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting the results you showed and in the order you showed them

```
SELECT
    s.part_number, c.supplier_product, MIN(c.customer_code)
FROM
    supplier s
    LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT * FROM customer_lookup t 
        ) c

    ON s.part_number = c.customer_product
GROUP BY s.part_number, c.supplier_product
ORDER BY c.supplier_product DESC
```